# Using google fonts with d3.js and SVG

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to use a custom type face from google fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Quantico|Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I have used them with this css for normal text:

```
.customFont{
  font-family: 'Karla' ;
}

<h1 class="customFont"> My text </h1>
```

But when I try to add this type face with d3.js in SVG text elements (e.g. node text in a graph) it removes all other styling I try to add to the class:

```
.customFont {
  font-family: 'Karla' ;
  font-weight : bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  stroke:#fff;
  stroke-width:1px;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill: #000;
}
```

it changes the font-family to the custom Karla but it doesn't keep all the other properties. How can I get the new type face and the other properties in one class?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to set the font?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this by adding an `<defs>` tag and appending a `<style type="text/css">` tag within in that at the top of my SVG. You can then add text to the style tag and import your google fonts like so:

```
    var root = d3.select(element)
                 .append('svg')
                 .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                 .attr('xmlns:xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
                 .attr('version', '1.1')
                 .attr('xml:space', 'preserve')
                 .attr('height', '100%')
                 .attr('width', '100%')
                 .attr('viewBox', '0 0 0 0');

        root.append('defs')
            .append('style')
            .attr('type', 'text/css')
            .text("@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800');");
```

I did this within an angular application I was working on, but that doesn't matter. This can be applied to any D3 example. All thats left to do is to take your `<text>` tags in your SVG and apply the appropriate font styles to them (font-family, font-size, font-weight, etc etc):

```
var svg = root.append('g').attr('class', 'root');

    svg.append('text')
       .text(scope.$parent.heading)
       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
       .style('font-size', '14px')
       .style('font-family', '"Open Sans", sans-serif')
       .style('font-weight', '500');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is associated with not setting the font-size. The font-size will default differently in a < text > element then an html element. You probably don't need to set the fill-stroke either if you are trying to replicate the look from the html element (in your case < h1 >) to the < text > element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Quantico|Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .customFont {
          font-family: 'Karla' ;
          font-weight : bold;
          pointer-events: none;
          stroke:#fff;
          stroke-width:1px;
          fill-opacity: 1;
          fill: #000;
        }
        .customFont1 {
          font-family: 'Karla';
          font-size: 28px;
          font-weight : bold;
          pointer-events: none;
          fill-opacity: 1;
          fill: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="customFont"> My text </h1>
    <h1 class="customFont1"> My text </h1>
    <div>
        <svg>
            <g>
                <text x="0" y="20" class="customFont">My text</text>
            </g>
            <g>
                <text x="0" y="50" class="customFont1">My text</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwalter_4iqsolutions/664kxa9L/) showing some comparisons.

It doesn't include d3, but it does use svg which is ultimately what d3 creates.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the link in  as in

```
<head>
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Next, just add in css.

```
.axis text {
fill: #2b2929;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
font-size: 120%;
}
```

That works for me.