# how to add standard google fonts to D3.js svg text element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How do I add google fonts to d3 text element, for example:

```
   g.append('text')
      .attr('x', width / 2)
      .attr('y', height / 3)
      .text('roboto')
      .style("font-family", "roboto")
      .style("font-size", "80px")
      .attr("fill", "grey");
```

This is separate to the below question which focuses on *custom type face*

[Using google fonts with d3.js and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025876/using-google-fonts-with-d3-js-and-svg)

Answer (score -1):

The straight forward solution:

Use the link element, as shown below, in your layout's head

```
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This imports the font in question, and then within your svg element add the font family:

```
 svg.append('text')
      .text('Inconsolata')
      .style("font-family", "Inconsolata")
```